# .NET 5 Blazor Server: settings per host

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app that is available via multiple domain names. Based on the host I would like to set some state. Therefore I created a scoped service:

```
services.AddScoped<MyState>();
```

I also created Middleware to set variables in the `MyState` object based on the host, something like:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, MyState myState)
{
    switch(context.Request.Host.Host) {
        "example.com":
            myState.variable = 1;
            break;
...
```

And register the middleware before `app.UseEndpoints`

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyStateMiddleware>();
```

This all works well. I can see everything is set based on the domain name.
But then suddenly it looks like the `MyState` service is being reconstructed.

I tried debugging this without luck.

Could this be happening because I use my own `AuthenticationStateProvider`?
It looks things go wrong after the app is authorized.
Does authorization change the scope so all scoped services are re-created?

And the real question: how to create a state based on the host/domain name?

Edit: By the way, I also set the `CultureInfo` for each host in the middleware. This is not being reset after authorization.

Comment: In Blazor Server the scope is the client circuit/session. New `MyState` instances will be created and destroyed for each client session. Besides, isn't that `myState.variable` *session* specific? A single client will connect using a single HOST value. Unless you want all clients to see changes to `variable` at the same time, you can treat it as a session variable with an initial value based on HOST

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know the scoped service is initiated each client session, but it almost looks like after authorization a new session is started. Which is rather unexpected.
I also tried setting initial values based on the host, but that crashed Blazor after the authorization without any logs or errors. But I am going to retry this again, maybe I now see what is going on. Thank you.

Comment: `after authorization a new session is started.` that's the point. The anonymous "user"(session) before authentication isn't the same as the authenticated user/session. What *do* you want to do? Provide initial values? Or provide values whose changes are visible to everyone? .NET Core's Configuration already provides both through the Options classes by the way

Comment: If you have a single server, a singleton `ConcurrrentDictionary<>` can be used to hold values per host, essentially acting as an in-memorry cache. You'll have to use it through a service though, to prevent "client" code from modifying it.

Comment: `The anonymous "user"(session) before authentication isn't the same as the authenticated user/session.` Ah, I did not know this. In my mind the session would continue for the same circuit but then set as authorized. I think this is my problem. A new scope is started after authorization but the middleware is never invoked at that moment because SignalR handles interaction with Javascript. Am I right?

Comment: I want to provide initial values (based on the host). This includes things like CSS color that should be available to everyone but should never change for a host. So I am going to take another route and take a look at the options classes or ConcurrrentDictionary. Thank you.

Comment: That's custom styling/theming/skinning, not custom values. There may be something built-in already, loading the custom styles in `_layout`.  Even if there's no built-in way, someone probably created a package for this. Theming is a common requirement for all ASP.NET stacks. In fact, if you check the demo sites of most UI libraries you'll see a `Theme` picker in one form or another. In fact there's always been a market for custom themes for ASP.NET

Comment: Well not only theming, there are other settings as well like different company profiles and language settings for each host.

Comment: Check for example the demo of [Blazorise](https://bootstrapdemo.blazorise.com/). Theming is provided by [a ThemeProvider  component](https://blazorise.com/docs/theming/) that wraps the `Router` at the very top of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the middleware.  You can get the information and set the state in `App`.  Example code below:

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Value="this">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    [Inject] private NavigationManager NavManager { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var url = NavManager.BaseUri;
        //  Set your state
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

You can then put in some break points and see what your authenication code is up to if the state gets reset.

Comment: Well in this case I also would like to have this state in `_Host.cshtml` (to change the stylesheet for example).

Comment: @ThomasHuijzer see my answer on this point

Comment: Also  see this note of mine https://shauncurtis.github.io/posts/DynamicCss.html

Answer (score 0):

In answer to switching behaviour based on domain in `_Host.cshtml` I have this in my file:

```cs
@page "/"
@namespace MyApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
    // get brand
    var brand = MyApp.Branding.Brand.GetFromRequest(new ControllerRequest(Request));
}
```

The `Request` here is the Razor page's `HttpRequest` object which has properties such as `.Host` and `.Cookies` which you can use.